# Moving EntityModel from root directory to model folder result in errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity

I created entityframework on root directory, after moving it to model directory I get this error:

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Employee' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Melsco2016' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
Line 27:     
Line 28:     
Line 29:     public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable<Melsco2016.Employee>> {
Line 30:         
Line 31: #line hidden

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
Files\root\6c3c13cf\e07d3222\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.3vqwrhbc.0.cs
Line: 29
```

Comment: What is namespace of your models ?

Comment: But i has been changed now i think it would be now Melcso2016.Models.

Comment: Ye worked fine After Melsco2016.Models thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your namespace has been changed.It would be now `Melsco2016.Models`

Try using `Melsco2016.Models.Employee`